# call methods of component from directive in angular 2

Tags: angular

this is my code directive:

```typescript
import { Directive, HostListener, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appScrollToEnd]'
}) 
export class ScrollToEndDirective {
  constructor(private element: ElementRef) { }
  @HostListener('scroll') onScroll(){
    console.log(this.element
  } 
}
```

and in my view template

```typescript
<div class="content" appScrollToEnd="functionInComponent($event)"></div>
```

How can i call methods `functionInComponent()` when scroll. i know angular2 can listen event scroll, but my purpose is call method of component from directive. Thank

Comment: `functionInComponent($event)` it's a function defined in controller ?
I mean, main controller ?

Comment: Not sure if it helps, but you may have a @Output event in your directive, and you may bind the same wherever you are using it to some component method, Cheers!!

Comment: @MadhuRanjan Yeah i think it can help https://plnkr.co/edit/bhSP2GVtKpBy46wZlhUZ?p=preview

Comment: thank for your example, i understand :)

Comment: @MadhuRanjan Consider posting your comment as answer)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have a @Output event in your directive, and bind the same wherever you are using it to some component method,

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[appScrollToEnd]'
}) 
export class ScrollToEndDirective {
  @Output() appScrollToEnd = new EventEmitter();

  constructor(private element: ElementRef) { }

  @HostListener('scroll') onScroll(){
    this.appScrollToEnd.emit('someValue');
  } 
}


@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div class="content" (appScrollToEnd)="functionInComponent($event)">
      <div class="text">Some text</div> 
    </div>
  `,
})
export class App {
  functionInComponent(e) {
    console.log(e):
  }
}
```

Thanks @yurzui for the Plunker sample.

Here is the [Plunker!!](https://plnkr.co/edit/bhSP2GVtKpBy46wZlhUZ?p=preview)

Answer (score 2):

Why not injecting the actual component like

```
  constructor(private _App : App ) { }

 @HostListener('scroll') onScroll(){
    this._App.functionInComponent('someValue');
  }
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/IgG1c3e6BzLkAex7g73r?p=preview

Comment: what if the directive is needed on multiple components?